# Problems Creating Shapekeys from Armature modifier

Tags: animation, shape-keys

I’m currently using the CookieFlexRig character (I’ve linked it below) and I want to be able to add more shapekeys. Ideally I’m hoping to add shapekeys from posing (by going into the modifiers and applying as shapekey). Unfortunately, every time I try doing that, the shapekey doesn’t work (it might be due to the fact that there are two armatures? I’m not sure).

Character blend file link: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52939

If someone could please help me figure out how to add additional shapekeys, even if it’s a different solution than using the bones to pose, I would really really appreciate it.

Thank you

Comment: Hi! I've checked the file. You're right, it's because the two Armature modifiers. This a very specific so I better edited the post a little.

Comment: I've tested and it looks that if you delete the second Armature modifier, it'll work. It might be a better solution, though. But if you can work with that second one, just do that.